# Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "constructor-arg"

Tags: spring

I am new to the Spring framework. While trying constructor DI I am getting this exception.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "vlaue" must be declared for element type "constructor-arg".

Here by spring.xml file for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

 <beans>
     <bean id="kaka" class="com.spring.test.FootballPlayer">
           <constructor-arg type="int" vlaue="7"/>
     </bean>

     <bean id="forlan" class="com.spring.test.FootballPlayer">
           <constructor-arg value="10"/>
     </bean>

     <bean id="predator" class="com.spring.test.Predator"/>
 </beans>
```

Shall we use both constructor-arg and property tags for a same bean?

Answer (score 2):

Please correct following:

```
 <bean id="kaka" class="com.spring.test.FootballPlayer">
           <constructor-arg type="int" vlaue="7"/>
     </bean>
```

to

```
 <bean id="kaka" class="com.spring.test.FootballPlayer">
           <constructor-arg type="int" value="7"/>
     </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spring XML is invalid cause of the typo in the kaka bean. This is what the error means!

You should replace vlaue with value.